# Unauthorized use of checking account

Tags: banking

Can a friend legally write checks and use debit card on my account without authorization?

Answer (score 0):

Not without authorization from an account holder, no. Legally, that would be the same as if a stranger had stolen the card or checkbook and made use of it.

Now if you had given your friend the PIN or other authorization information on the card, that would constitute at least an implied permission to use it.